# bootstrap-vue: b-form-datepicker doesn't update to v-model until it's hovered

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm using `b-form-datepicker`and I'd like to use an additional button which would reset the selected date to a default state. The button also resets another datepicker, an input form and a dropdown-multiselect. I have successfully implemented this, however, when I click reset, the datepickers are not updated immediately but only if they are hovered or clicked.

Here is the mark-up:

```
<b-btn
  variant="primary"
  class="mr-2"
  @click="resetSearch"
>
  <font-awesome-icon
    icon="undo"
    class="mr-sm-1"
  />
  <span class="d-sm-inline-block d-none">Reset</span>
</b-btn>

<b-form-datepicker
  id="minDate"
  v-model="minDate"
  size="lg"
  today-button
  close-button
  start-weekday="1"
  value-as-date
  locale="en-GB"
/>

<b-form-datepicker
  id="maxDate"
  v-model="maxDate"
  size="lg"
  today-button
  close-button
  start-weekday="1"
  value-as-date
  locale="en-GB"
/>
```

This is how I set the model initially

```
created () {
  this.minDate = this.$moment().subtract(5, 'years').toDate()
  this.maxDate = this.$moment().toDate()
  this.dataLoaded = true
}
```

This is the `resetSearch` method

```
resetSearch () {
  this.publicationsSearchKeyword = ''
  this.minDate = this.$moment().subtract(5, 'years').toDate()
  this.maxDate = this.$moment().toDate()
  this.publicationsListValue = []
}
```

Here is a codepen : https://codepen.io/BBA278/pen/vYOxBgz

Any ideas how should I build this in order for the selected date to update immediately on reset button click?

Comment: It'd be great if you provide codpen or jsFiddle link...

Comment: @bravemaster Thank you for trying to help and apologies, should have added one initially. I have updated the question.

Comment: This is really stupid. I tried in codepen but I don't know what the reason is. It won't update until I hover or click on it. Using reset button and reset value might be a workaround, although it's not exactly what you want.
Maybe it's the expected behavior. They designed datepicker to work like this :)

Comment: @bravemaster Happy that at least I'm not the only one noticing this issue. Using the provided reset button is not an option for us because we want everything to reset on one button click. Bear in mind, the datepicker was added about 10 days ago so there might be a fix soon. Cheers for looking into anyway.

Comment: https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/4827

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went to [github repository](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue) to open an issue on this one. However, a similar issue was on top of the list: [Datepicker doesn't update value without hovering over it](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/4827)

They say it was fixed in a pull request:

> Actually this is fixed in PR [#4824](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/pull/4824)

Maybe in v.2.6.0 it will be fixed.

### Update:

Bootstrap v2.6.0 has been released in Mar. 05, 2020 and it includes the bug fix of this issue.

> [**Bug Fixes v2.6.0**](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/reference/changelog#v260)
>
> **b-form-date-picker**:  menu focus handling for Firefox and Safari on MacOS, and fix v-model update issue (closes #4814, #4827) ([#4824](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/4824)) (09fa920)

Comment: The bug will be fixed in v2.6.0.. Hopefully being released this week.

Comment: BootstrapVue 2.6.0 has been released, which includes a fix for this.